# Difference between set up and setup?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, orthography

I have been working on some piece of code recently, and I noticed a subtle tweak in the usage of a word. When creating a method about setting things in place, I noticed it was called `setUp`.

In this domain, this is called Camel Case, and it means that it should be read in two parts. So it is supposed to be read `set up`. However, I always used this as a single word, `setup`.

Is there any difference between the two? Is one of them wrong?

Comment: One is a verb, and the other is a noun. Two very different meanings. The difference is akin to "login" vs "log in" and "sign up" vs "signup".

Comment: I'd advise not getting too hung up on the grammar of variable names in software.

Comment: It may be a duplicate indeed, they need to improve the research engine :(